# 50 MHz Clock shifting from 5 V to 3.3 V and Bidirectional , possible?

Tags: clock, level-shifting, high-frequency

I'm trying to design a circuit to convert a 50 MHz clock source from 5 V to 3.3 V. At first, I thought of using Sparkfun's level translator shown in the link below:

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide

However, the NMOS used there, the BSS138, has delay and rise times that are unsuitable for the 50 MHz clock signal. It has a delay time of 2.5 ns and a rise time of 9 ns when turning on. Similarly, it has a 20 ns delay and a 7 ns fall time when turning off.

I tried to look for solutions that are similar to the converter, but most of them don't seem to be suited for MHz signals. Some solutions show using ICs such as the SN74LVC8T245, but it's direction depends on the input to the direction pin, and the rise times seem unsuitable given the clock signal. Other solutions such as a resistor divider seem to work for lower frequencies, but I want to ensure signal integrity as this is a clock signal. Using a faster NMOS would be ideal and simplistic, and I can replicate the Sparkfun circuit for multiple lines, but what other solutions would be optimal for this fast clock signal?

EDIT: Since there has been some discussion regarding the need for bi-directionalaity, I wanted to explain a bit here. Initially, we thought that we could go with the level translator. One channel would be available for shifting the clock from 5 to 3.3 V, and the remaining channels would be used as needed for other purposes. But, due to the specs of the BSS138, it didn't seem reliable for our 50 MHz clock. After some discussion, being bi-directional is no longer a requirement, at least for the clock signal, so we're just focusing on shifting the clock down for now. I'm really sorry about mentioning bi-direction. Let's just forget about it for now. We plan for the clock signal to be stepped down, and then it should go into another module that accepts 3.3 V as an input. I don't know the load capacitance or impedance of the module, but when I find that out, I'll update here accordingly.

EDIT: So, after ignoring the bi-directional functionality, I think I may have found a potential solution: to use a buffer to step it down from 5V to 3.3 V while keeping signal integrity. I found some buffers that seem to work from TI, the SN74LV1T34 and the SN74LV1T126.

http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LV1T34/description

http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LV1T126/description

I imported the model of the SN74LV1T126 into LTspice and ran a simulation, hooking it up to 3.3 V and a 50 MHz 5-volt clock source, showing the output voltage with and without a load. Ideally, I would have liked to test out the SN74LV1T34, but there are no SPICE models available for it, so I'm just working with the SN74LV1T126. The image is shown below:

[image: Logic Level Sim 1]

Here, I'm just showing one clock cycle so that I can measure the rise and fall times to see if it is within acceptable tolerances given the clock input. Judging by the sim, it seems to work well, but when under a load, it doesn't reach 3.3 V, but rather it falls down to 1.8 V. Since this is going to be hooked up to a module, it will be under load, so is there anything I can do to ensure it reaches the correct voltage?

Comment: If you have "clock source", why your level-shifting circuit needs to be "bi-directional"?

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1878621.pdf?_ga=2.181151079.1543500198.1505770991-15521511.1499714337

Comment: I would like to future proof it just in case of the possibility that we may need to go the opposite direction from 3.3 to 5 V, if possible. If not, then, I'll just accept that we can only go one direction and move on.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your future proof concept, not knowing what the project entails and all, but if you are worried about needing it at 5V again, well then you could just take it directly from the source...

Comment: What is your load capacitance ?  WHat is your transmission line impedance?  Consider that 3.3V CMOS logic is around 25 Ohm output impedance and 5V logic is around 50 ohms

Comment: @user101402 that is kind of a silly requirement. One doesn't later change the clocking on a hunch. That will require relevant redesign anyway.

Comment: What makes you think 50MHz bi-directional level shifter is even possible? The current state of the art by Maxim this year is (not 16) but 8 MHz and I2C limit is 3.2MHz. DO you know why there is a limit?

Comment: I'm trying to undestand where one would want a bidirectional clock, at such a high speed. Maybe a multi-master SPI bus? But, in that case, can't you use a GPIO to control the data direction of a level translator?

Comment: I'm really sorry about making it bi-directional. That was dumb, so I'm just trying to just step it down one way, ignoring the need for it to be bi-directional. So, ignoring that, it should be definitely possible. The PCA9306 seems promising, but I can't find a model to use in LTspice to verify that it will work. @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 You mentioned that it would work at higher frequencies when designed properly. 50 MHz is fast, so what do you have to be careful of when working with such a fast signal?

Comment: dont use birectional, buffer it and read books about High speed layout design , stripline etc , my original answer was correct

Comment: A 50 ohm load would be uncommon, try your sim into something a little more reasonable.

Comment: @DanMills Thanks for your comment, but why would a 50 ohm load be uncommon? If the input impedance of the module that I'm sending the clock to is 50 ohms, shouldn't I model it like this? Since TonyStewart mentioned that CMOS logic is 25 ohm output impedance, I'm trying to find out what kind of module will the clock be going to in order to check the impedance of the inputs to ensure proper modeling.

Comment: 50 Ohms is very common in RF applications, just not in stuff that is expecting to be driven by cmos directly. Most chip clock inputs intended go run as slow as a mere 50MHz will be bog standard voltage mode CMOS, or possibly LVDS or PECL both of which are basically variations on 100 ohm differential. The only place you see 50 ohms is when it is intended to terminate a coax line, which is a different sort of application from on board logic.

Comment: @DanMills Well, the module that I'm sending the clock to is a PIXIE NIM module. http://www.xia.com/DGF_Pixie-16.html   Its inputs are 50 ohms, though as this is a clock signal, I don't know exactly how the clock will be inputted into the module. I'm just going by the specifications.

Comment: Looks like you can either configure a clock input on the front, in which case 50 Ohms on a coax (SMA from the look of it) looks right, or via the backplane, you would need more data then there is on that web site to be sure what the appropriate interface is. I would in particular expect that 50 ohm interface to need more like 0dBm then several volts up it (But it will probably accept a wide range of drive levels).

Comment: @DanMills I'm not sure how my team will connect from the 3.3 V clock to the PIXIE module; I'm just working under the assumption that its one of the 50 ohm SMA connectors. Assuming that this is the case, putting the 50 ohm load onto the output as shown in my image doesn't seem to produce the 3.3 V output as expected. I'll just have to do more research on another buffer that might work.

Comment: @DanMills If the connector is rated to have an impedance of 50 ohms, is the way I'm modeling it correct in the schematic? I'm not sure if the connector can be considered a load, so would it make sense to just put a resistor on it like that and call it a connector, or is it fine like that since what the output of the SN74LV1T126 sees is a 50 ohm load if you just simplify it down to its impedance?

Comment: @DanMills Sorry, found out the possible issue. The SN74LV1T126 is rated for 7 mA, and I need more to ensure that it's 3.3 V under a 50 ohm load, at least 66 mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you can suddenly jump from a speed limit of 3.2MHz for I2C speed3 to 50MHz without impedance control on drivers on both sides , careful shielding and controlled T-line impedance with a low RdsOn open-drain switch that rises in Coss, Ciss as RdsOn is reduced.

### Line driver load RC time constants rule the maximum speed

- when you dont follow controlled impedance lines.

Here is the fastest one at <s>16</s> 8 MHz that I found. (2017) with Nch FETs

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14591.pdf

But in BJT series switches one can get <3.3ns max rise\fall times into 300 Ohm loads= 30pF using the PCA3060 suggested by @BruceAbbot

**However even this may not work on I2C at 50 MHz**

> The PCA9306 has a standard open−collector
>   configuration of the I2C−bus. The size of these pull−up
>   resistors depends on the system, but each side of the
>   translator must have a pull−up resistor. The device is
>   designed to work with Standard−mode, Fast−mode and Fast
>   mode Plus I2C−bus devices in addition to SMBus devices.
>
> ### The maximum frequency is dependent on the RC timeconstant, but generally supports > 2 MHz

- but The maximum frequency is totally dependent upon the
  specifics of the application and the device can operate > 
  33 MHz. Basically, the PCA9306 behaves like a wire with
  the additional characteristics of transistor device physics
  and should be capable of performing at higher frequencies
  if used correctly
  Let's consider non-bidirectional clock and data buffers level shifters first.

This is one approach using stripline= 50 ohms and 25 Ohm 5V logic  74LVC' or 74LVA' family.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f32hOK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is old school using 74ACL and 74ACL2 but works.

---

Now there are so many different logic families to consider that do NOT need level shifters for unidirectional signals.

[image]
REF

1. http://focus.ti.com/pdfs/logic/lvabrochure.pdf
2. http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sdyu001ab/sdyu001ab.pdf

Comment: How is this bidirectional?

Comment: LIke Ali said, why does a Clock have to be bidirectional  Does it have to be tri-state too?

Comment: I guess he is trying to break I2C speed records with an open drain switch.

Comment: No, my guess is that OP wants to interface a 5-V oscillator 5x3 chip with a 3.3V input to a uP or FPGA.

Comment: Well then a series switch is not going to work well.  Even the PCA3060 behaves like a wire with >30MHz possible. spec says , 
the additional characteristics of transistor device physics
and should be capable of performing at higher frequencies
if used correctly.

Comment: Why are you talking about I2C? What's 3.2 MHz got to do with anything?

Comment: I'm sorry about the bi-directional requirement. After some thought, I'm just trying to have it go one-way right now. I looked at the PCA9306, and it seems that it would fit my needs due to the fast switching rise and fall times, so it seems that it would work for a 50 MHz signal. However, I'm attempting to find a model of it to test in LTspice, and TI's model is only in HSPICE. Also, where does 3.2 MHz have to do with anything?

Comment: PCA9306 is not a buffer,  delete  bidirectional in question , follow stripline impedance control books , read the rest of my answer again. Understand ringing , transmission lines and layout design is not trivial.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thanks for your reply. As I learn more about the physical restrictions on my design, I'll be sure to look up the topics you mentioned as I progress with my design. All I know for now (unless this suddenly changes) is that this will be fitted into a NIM module frame so there are design limitations. With any luck, the buffer can be placed as close as possible to the inputs and outputs to decrease impedance, but as of now, more information is needed. At the very least, the buffers that you referred to will definitely step down the clock signal to the appropriate voltage.

Comment: The logic families in the table may be used directly but use stripline tracks.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I apologize for asking so many questions from you, but you wouldn't happen to know of a good buffer SPICE model would you? It's hard to find a part that will fit my needs and has a SPICE model that I can simulate.

Comment: just read the specs of 74LVCxxx parts like  I suggested that accept 5Vin with low latency and unless you model the track impedance , load and stray capacitance, simulations are less useful

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One thing that occurred to me while researching was transmission line effects. The cable length is 6 ft (1.83 m), so in the worst case, the voltage will drop at the input, so I'm also trying to research how to design with the TL in mind. I don't think that just matching the (assumed) 50 ohm impedance of the cable will be enough.

Comment: ALso unless the source is 50 ohms like 74LVCxxx parts @5V you can understand 20~30 pf /ft ribbon or twisted pair will affect rise time.

Answer (score 3):

Well, while I do not understand the need for bidirectional (for a clock of all things?) there is one component that would seem to fit the bill...

Introducing the humble transformer!

Something like an FT50-61 with maybe 10 turns tapped at 6 and cap coupled in and out, dc restore with a couple of 220 ohm resistors, would seem to fit the bill.

Very standard fare in RF design, but possibly not that often seen on a logic board these days!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was just focused on FETs and ICs, that I never considered a transformer. In theory, a transformer would work, but I wouldn't think that you could just a transformer and have it step down from 5 to 3.3. What else would you have to add to a circuit to make it reliable?

Comment: user101402 has no idea about impedance control, unintended radiation for EMC, and has much to learn about design from books.